# Mother and daughter conflict

Tags: allah, women

my mom and I were fighting and I told her something really awful, I repented for my mistake but she is still sad about what I said, will Allah forgive me?

Answer (score -1):

You must ask your mom for forgiveness and say that I will never do this again. After this Allah will be pleased with you Insha’Allah this is shaitans plan to let shaitan make you talk smack to your mom. Allah knows best

Answer (score -1):

In fact Allah is so kind and merciful but God is sensitive to respect for parents.
The first step is that Apologize to your mother.for example kiss her hand to win her heart.
If you do it, you will definitely be forgiven.

You will definitely succeed.

Comment: Please check on [answer] for more information about how to answer a question